# Similar rows in model (PHP laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on eloquent models, and I have a model `TheSeries` and I would like to display similar series based on `TheGenres` model.

In your opinion, where this should be done between controller or model in Laravel?

Can you help give me an example of code, so I can understand how to return similiar series based on genreID/genreName from `TheGenres` model. Thanks.

I need same query but in Laravel\Eloquent way:

```
SELECT m2.* FROM mSeriesGenres m1 

    INNER JOIN mSeriesGenres m2 
        ON m1.genreID = m2.genreID 
    JOIN TheSeries m3 
        ON m3.id = m1.seriesID 

WHERE m1.seriesID = 13 AND m2.seriesID <> 13
GROUP BY m2.seriesID HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mSeriesGenres WHERE seriesID = 13)
```

I would like to point out that mSeriesGenres is the many-to-many table.

Comment: In the repository, your models - describe the data set, controllers handle the logic, the repository - crunches all that together. This will result in much cleaner code which is easier to maintain

Comment: Hmm, thanks, is this the one: andersao/l5-repository ?

Comment: No need for extra packages, you can define them yourself easily, you can google for more more tuts. This is definitely the way to go, especially when your application grows. https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Comment: Can you give me an example, how I would return 3 similar series based on genres? There are a lot of methods, but I would like to see how others would do it, to make it sure that mine is correct.

Comment: This depends heavily on your app structure, if you're using many-to-many or not, checks if a minimum amount of "similar content" is displayed etc. A basic check would required matching genre_id

Comment: I do have many to many relationship declared in eloquent.

Comment: I need a eloquent query which will display series, based on many-to-many relationship of `TheSeries` with `TheGenres`, I dont know what to use , to achieve that. I just started.

Comment: I see, this part of the docs is for you then :) check the whereHas() mtehod https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a repository pattern approach:

https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/